# How can I append or concatenate or merge more than 2 numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 numpy arrays of this shape

```
(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)
(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)
(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)
(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)
```

And I want to merge them into a single array. The shape will be:

```
(4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)
```

**Trial 1**

`np.append(f1, f2, axis=0)` which has a shape of `(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)`

How can I do this?

Or is there another way to manage this data?

The only thing I am certain about, the 4 arrays are of the same shape.

**Trial 2**

```
np.concatenate(f1, f2, f3)
```

Error:

```
----> 1 np.concatenate(f1, f2, f3)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: `np.concatenate([f1, f2, f3, f4], axis=0)`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks!

Comment: @maximusdooku You'd do good to accept the suggested answer, as it solved your problem...

Comment: Just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your arrays in a list then use `np.concatenate`:

```
import numpy as np
l = [np.ones((1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14))] * 4
a = np.concatenate(l, axis=0)
a.shape
Out[9]: (4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 14)
```